# Display not utilizing all of the monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell Studio xps 16 notebook.  I've done a fresh install of Win 7 with my new SSD.  I've got 2 monitors hooked up

Primary. an acer h243h through HDMI
Secondary. a hanns g through VGA

My primary monitor was great until...it seemed...after a random reboot that it stopped using all of the screen real-estate.  There's a black bar of unused space around everything.

The monitor is at the optimal resolution (1920x1080).
I've installed the monitor drivers.
I've installed the most current video drivers.
I've poured over all of the windows settings and the settings on the monitor itself.

Any suggestions for how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the monitor settings not include width/height options?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from your optimal resolution and then back (make sure you apply the changes in between.)

Failing that try playing around with different resolutions until you find one that displays properly (yes, even though it isn't working at what it should be working at.)

I have seen this a number of times and in every case it has been the resolution.

Comment: I tried but to no avail.

Comment: Does the OSD menu have adjustments for the vertical and horizontal distances? Try playing around with them too.

Comment: No adjustments for that.  Thanks for the attempt.